# How can i get the length of a curl Post body

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to log in to a remote website which requires me to post username password and login via post. I am using the Curl Option

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS , $postData);
```

and assign my info like this

```
$postData['email'] = 'smart@acme.com';
$postData['password'] = 'Secret';
$postData['Submit']='Login';
```

But the remote server complains about

```
HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length.
```

So how can i tell the content length of my postData ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20487785/curl-content-length-required-error-3-days-of-searching-no-luck

Comment: This does not address my issue as post_body is an array so $strLen does not work

Comment: A HTTP POST's body is just ascii. It has no idea what an array is. You convert the array to a query string and get the string's length.

Answer (score 0):

To get the length of PostData, you can use PHP's function `count` to get it.

Try:

```
#Get the length
$postData_len = count($postData);

#Set Curl Header with Content Length
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Length: '.$postData_len));
```

The above code with calculate the length of the postData array and then set the Curl header, if you're looking for 1 line of code, try this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Length: '.count($postData)));
```

Comment: $postData is an Array and Length on Array does not work

Comment: @MisterniceGuy answer has been updated, try using this example and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Not sure this will work for you or not?** but you need something like this with `strlen()` to set **Content-Length**.

```
$postData= array("email" => "smart@acme.com", "password" => "Secret","Submit"=>"Login");                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($postData);                                                                                   

$ch = curl_init('http://api.remote.com');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ch = curl_init();
$data['email'] = 'smart@acme.com';
$data['password'] = 'Secret';
$data['Submit']='Login';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, '****/upload.php');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

curl_exec($ch);
```

the header of the request is

> [CONTENT_LENGTH] => 357
>
> [CONTENT_TYPE] => multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------aac448045c2fe517

however if we pass the args through string like this

```
$ch = curl_init();
$data['email'] = 'smart@acme.com';
$data['password'] = 'Secret';
$data['Submit']='Login';

echo strlen(http_build_query($data));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, '*/upload.php');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));

curl_exec($ch);
```

and the header of this request is

> [CONTENT_LENGTH] => 51
>
> [CONTENT_TYPE] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded

so it is better to use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` than `multipart/form-data` for it is easy to calculate content-length